# If I leave South Africa to visit a neighboring country, will I get a fresh 90 day stay upon coming back?

Tags: visas, south-africa, visa-extensions, visa-runs

I am a South African returning to live the country after having lived in the UK for the past 15 years. I returned on a UK passport (on a 90 day tourist visa) hoping to re-apply for my South African passport whilst here. I have found that I have run out of time to complete this process before my 90 day tourist visa expires. Can I simply take a couple of days vacation in a neighboring country and re-enter? What is the likelihood of getting a further 90 day visa?

Comment: Are you a South African citizen then? Citizens can enter and stay in their country any time. I do not understand.

Comment: Are you a South African citizen, but don't have a South African passport? If you can prove your citizenship by some other method, you don't have to leave the country at all.

Comment: You don't have your old "green ID book" stashed away somewhere? This would certainly prove that you're a citizen and allowed to stay indefinitely. There may be some technicalities due to you having entered with your UK passport though and overstaying without some sort of change-of-status might cause trouble if/when you leave or try to re-enter using the same passport.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because of the added complication of the asker potentially being a South African citizen. However, since they've not returned to clarify their citizenship, I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if they're South African, it's an Expats.SE kind of question